# Symfony 2.2 exception

Tags: php, symfony

I work with Symfony2 and I want to display a list of information in a table, but it has generated me the following exception:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "id" for route "affaire_voir_affaire" must match "\d+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in AffaireBundle:Affaires:affaires.html.twig at line 27.

```
thats is Routing.yml:

affaire_liste_affaires:
    pattern:  affaires/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AffaireBundle:Affaires:lister, page: 1 } 
    requirements:
        page:  \d*
affaire_voir_affaire:
    pattern:  /{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AffaireBundle:Affaires:voir }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
affaire_afficherformulaire_affaire:
    pattern:  ajouter
    defaults: { _controller: AffaireBundle:Affaires:afficherFormulaire }   
affaire_ajouterPC_affaire:
    pattern:  ajouterPompe_Chaleur
    defaults: { _controller: AffaireBundle:Affaires:ajouterPC }   
affaire_modifier_affaire:
    pattern:  modifier/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AffaireBundle:Affaires:modifier } 
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
affaire_supprimer_affaire:
    pattern: supprimer/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AffaireBundle:Affaires:supprimer }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+

affaire_rechercher_affaire:
    pattern: rechercher
    defaults: { _controller: AffaireBundle:Affaires:rechercher }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception message is quite obvious in my opinion. You require the `id` parameter of your route to match the regular expression `\d+` (wich is a number) and your call differs from that. You probably pass the wrong parameter to the twig `path()` method. Also be aware that for that rout only `POST` is allowed as an HTTP-Method so be sure to check for that aswell.